# Laravel Cashier Reuse Payment Intent

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I just upgraded my stripe integration in my Laravel application that handles subscriptions using Cashier 11.0 to get along to the new SCA rules.

All of this is working fine. :)

But when are subscriber is shown the cashier.payment route, how do i handle the situation where a user clicks on the button "GO Back"

I use this code to show the confirmation:

```
redirect()->route('cashier.payment',[$exception->payment->id, 'redirect' => route('settings.user.profile')]);
```

When the user click on the button "Go Back" I end up with a subscription with the status of "Incomplete"

How do i add a button, that the user can click on to confirm the payment on a later date?

Please help.